# Mysql query. Need search full name with first name and last name and wise versa

Tags: mysql

Mysql query. Need search full name with first name and last name and wise versa.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pm_id, CONCAT(c.last_name, ' ', c.first_name ) AS NAME
             FROM ap_plans p, ap_contacts c WHERE p.is_deleted=0 AND c.id = p.pm_id 
             AND p.URL = 'gettogether'  AND p.internal_project = 0
             AND c.staff_status=0 AND CONCAT_WS(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name ) LIKE '%Egill Olafsson%'  ORDER BY NAME
```

Here is my query. but I am able to get only first name, last name again if i try with last name with first name it is empty

Comment: Is putting the fullName as a new column an option? If so, just do that and use a full text index on that column.

Comment: have you tried to TRIM() last_name and first_name before concat? CONCAT(TRIM(c.last_name), ' ', TRIM(c.first_name))

Comment: Why are you using CONCAT_WS instead of CONCAT in your WHERE criterium?

Comment: *`CONCAT_WS(c.last_name,' ',c.first_name )`* concatenates a space and first name using last name as delimiter...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I found it should be in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pm_id, CONCAT(c.last_name, ' ', c.first_name ) AS NAME
             FROM ap_plans p, ap_contacts c WHERE p.is_deleted=0 AND c.id = p.pm_id 
             AND p.URL = 'gettogether'  AND p.internal_project = 0
             AND c.staff_status=0 AND (CONCAT(c.last_name, ' ', c.first_name ) LIKE '%Egill Olafsson%' OR CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name ) LIKE '%Egill Olafsson%') ORDER BY NAME
```